# Making a Scrollable UI in Libgdx

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

Okay So today I sat down to make a options panel that would allow you to scroll down through the list of options and for some reason I drew a blank... Anyone got an example at where I could get started for some reason I can't seem to see in my mind how to do it though It seems really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ScrollPane() as the container of your list. and you can use List and List.ListStyle to set your options list if you to use text for it.You should set the style of List.ListStyle and ScrollPane.ScrollPaneStyle linked to a json file and therefore your Skin. And then add a table to the stage containing the ScrollPane Actor.

here is a video tutorial: http://youtu.be/CNjkPPveqG8 talking about this.

PEACE!